# Sql server management studio : Load last used windows

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I use mostly the same 3 tables and about 4 queries.

Each time I need to log in Sql server management studio and open the corresponding 7 tables / queries one by one.

Can I set it somehow to remember them and at next start it would open these windows automatically?
Other Sql Tools do this without any special settings.

Thank you

Comment: Have you thought about saving these in a project/solution?

Comment: I haven't got "Save solution" only Close solution and Save All. If I click Save All and close  Sql server management studio and reopen again, the queries are there but not the other windows.

Comment: I created a solution but it can't remember of the windows either. I clicked save all but it didn't bother to reload when opening the solution again.

Comment: It isn't going to do that (and I don't think I'd want it to - what if my solution has 8,000 files?), but you can highlight any specific file from the solution explorer and it will open them...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733624/restore-tabs-after-reopening-sql-server-management-studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Prompt 6](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) includes a Tab History feature that records previously opened tabs and restores the SSMS workspace to how it was when you left off.

This isn't a free tool, but has a 14-day trial. If you get a chance to try it, do let us know whether it meets your needs as we're always looking for ways to improve the functionality.

Answer (score 4):

[SSMS Boost](http://www.ssmsboost.com/) also includes a history feature that I think will do what you want. It's a free add-on.

Comment: This doesn't work the way OP is looking for. Starting from the meaningless file names in history. But the feature is still useful in case of emergency.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but the content history is a pro/paid feature. That should at least be mentioned (unless it changed recently, in which case it is still important).

Answer (score 2):

Check out creating a shortcut to SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) using commandline options. [Microsoft SSMS Command Line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162825.aspx)

You have option to create a scriptfile, which would list the scripts you want to open at startup, or you could create an SSMS project, which would include the scripts you want, and open the project at SSMS startup.

```
Ssms Command Snytax
    [scriptfile] [projectfile] [solutionfile]
    [-S servername] [-d databasename] [-U username] [-P password] 
    [-E] [-nosplash] [-log [filename]?] [-?]
```