# Setting for SSMS to start with same pinned tabs as a previous session?

Tags: sql, ssms, ssms-2016

I can't find where this is possible. There's a similar setting in SSMSBoost but it's not saving the pinned tabs I created in this session.

Sometimes when the program crashes, it asks if I want to save what I have open, but it looks like it's asking to save each tab individually which isn't exactly what I'm talking about.

I'm just looking for many open tabs I have pinned and set in a specific order, to open up that way on my next startup. Possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurrect this, I got here searching for a way to always have RedGate SQL Search pinned when I open SSMS. I'm not aware of a way to have it reopen all tabs that were there when it closed, but I would love this feature myself. I'm also not sure about the pinned tabs.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733624/restore-tabs-after-reopening-sql-server-management-studio?rq=4) thread discusses the solutions some more, and another answer references some possible tools that do this.

I often create solutions for saved sets of queries, each solution geared towards a specific project, task or bug research, and it's handy to be able to open the solution and have all those tabs pop up.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35021237)